# Query causes msg 8115

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am unsure why the below query causes the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    (SUM(rLSP.PoundsMade) / (SUM(rLSAh.rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs) - (SUM(cast((PD. [End Time] 
    - PD.[Start Time]) as float)))))*(SUM(rLSPdt.DownTimeHrs)*(60*60) + SUM(rLSPdt.DownTimeMins)*60)
FROM 
    rpt_Line_Shift_Prod as rLSP
INNER JOIN 
    rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs as rLSAh ON rLSAh.LineNumber = rLSP.LineNumber
INNER JOIN 
    [Production Downtime] as PD ON rLSP.LineNumber = PD.[Line #]
INNER JOIN 
    rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime as rLSPdt ON rLSPdt.LineNumber = rLSP.LineNumber
GROUP BY
    PD.[Line #], rLSP.LineNumber, rLSAh.LineNumber;
```

How can I fix this error? I have used the same kind of `SUM` statement, where I cast a datetime as a float several times before, without errors.

Comment: Please include the table layouts for all the tables.  I'd be guessing one of these columns are not a numeric column: rLSP.PoundsMade, rLSAh.rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs, rLSPdt.DownTimeHrs, rLSPdt.DownTimeMins.  Also if the [End Time] and [Start Time] are truly datetime columns, you should be using DATEDIFF.

Comment: @Dbloch if one of the columns was not numeric the error message would much more likely be: `Conversion failed when converting the <type> value <value> to data type int.` or `Operand data type <type> is invalid for <...>.` if neither value is numeric, but here it is pretty clearly an `artithmetic overflow error`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the columns you use for the calculation use datatypes that could not hold the result of some of your calculations.

You can easily reproduce this if you try this for example:

```
DECLARE @IFlowOver TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Val INT)

INSERT @IFlowOver (Val)
    SELECT 2000000000


SELECT Val*Val FROM @IFlowOver
```

The `SELECT` throws the same error, because 2,000,000,000 times 2,000,000,000 cannot be represented in the int range.

To circumvent this you can just `CAST` the columns to a wider datatype for the calculation.
My above sample `SELECT` for example works if I cast to `BIGINT` for just the calculation:

```
SELECT CAST(Val AS BIGINT) * CAST(Val AS BIGINT) FROM @IFlowOver
```

But it also works if just one side is `CAST`

```
SELECT CAST(Val AS BIGINT) * Val FROM @IFlowOver
```

Comment: I tried casting it as a bigint, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3830080 what was "it" did you try it on all numeric column or just one? Plz show your column selections of your statement.

Comment: Well, I actually fixed it by using a "CONVERT(decimal(12,3), [insert calculations here])" statement. That didn't cause an Arithmetic overflow. Thanks though!